# Multiple conditional selection using list of variables

Tags: python, pandas

I'm cleaning up a data set and would like to filter it using a list of variables that satisfy a condition. Such as

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {"var1": [0,1,0,0,0],
        "var2": [0,0,0,0,0],
        "var3": [0,0,0,0,1],
        'var4': [0,0,0,0,0],
        'var5': [1,2,3,4,5]
       }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

#here is a list as an example
SelLst = ['var1','var2','var3','var4']

#This is what I'd like to do, but instead of 4 variables, I have any number.
b = df[SelLst ].query('var1 ==1 | var2 == 1 | var3 ==1 | var4 == 1')

#This doesn't work, but would be cool
c = df[df[SelLst ].isin([1])]

#Something like this works, but I feel like pandas has something under the hood that would be easier.
strSel = " ".join([i + '== 1 |' for i in SelLst])
d = df[SelLst].query(strSel[:-1])
```

so any magic functions or thoughts how to smooth this out? Or is that the way to do it? Thanks!

Comment: It seems to me like you are looking for `any()`

Comment: sure does. Looks like  e= df[df[SelLst].any(1)] is what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`isin` +`any(1)`

```
df[['var1','var2','var3','var4']].isin([1]).any(1)
Out[538]: 
0    False
1     True
2    False
3    False
4     True
dtype: bool
```